# Windows Server 2003 on components that have no driver support

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, ubuntu, virtualization, drivers

I recently got an i5 processor on an ASUS P7P55D LE motherboard to act as a cheap server only to realise that there are no windows 2003 drivers for the chipset and network. I haven't tried yet but can I install the XP drivers onto a 2003 machine and hope for it to work? Or should I go down the ubuntu virtualisation route?

If so, would I expect any performance issues with virtualisation of Win2K3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've installed heaps of XP drivers in Server 2003 and I'm yet to have any issues

Comment: awesome! 15char

Comment: any specific way of installing tho? or just run the regular installers? i've been reading up and have seen people swapping out cab files and whatnot

Comment: 90% of the time normally, the other 10% it's cos of a touchy installer, so I extract the files and update/install the driver through the device manager.

Answer (score 1):

Often enough you can just run the installers normally, however sometimes you might need to run them in compatibility mode!